# Pulseaudio: module-simple-protocol not listening

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, android, x-server, protocols

I did the following:

```bsh
$ pactl list sources short | grep "analog-stereo.monitor"
0       alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor      module-alsa-card.c      s16le 2ch   44100Hz    SUSPENDED
```

```bsh
echo "load-module module-simple-protocol-tcp source=0 record=true port=22345" >> /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

```bsh
$ pulseaudio --kill
$ pulseaudio --daemonize
$ pulseaudio --start
$ pulseaudio --check; echo $?
0
$ ss -lt
State      Recv-Q     Send-Q         Local Address:Port            Peer Address:Port     Process     
LISTEN     0          5                  127.0.0.1:7200                 0.0.0.0:*                    
LISTEN     0          4096               127.0.0.1:8384                 0.0.0.0:*                    
LISTEN     0          511                127.0.0.1:46561                0.0.0.0:*                    
LISTEN     0          511                  0.0.0.0:http                 0.0.0.0:*                    
LISTEN     0          4096           127.0.0.53%lo:domain               0.0.0.0:*                    
LISTEN     0          5                  127.0.0.1:ipp                  0.0.0.0:*                    
LISTEN     0          512                        *:8096                       *:*                    
LISTEN     0          4096                       *:22000                      *:*                    
LISTEN     0          511                     [::]:http                    [::]:*                    
LISTEN     0          10                         *:1716                       *:*                    
LISTEN     0          5                      [::1]:ipp                     [::]:*
```

### Observation

The server is still not listening on the port 22345! **Any suggestions?**

---

## Another problem

When I comment out (with `#` in the beginning of the line) `load-module module-simple-protocol-tcp source=0 record=true port=22345` in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and restart *pulseaudio* (as  described above), no sound comes out of my laptop anymore. **Any suggestions?**

After commenting out, I don't see `analog-stereo.monitor` anymore!

```bsh
$ pactl list sources short
0       auto_null.monitor       module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
```

### Observation

It worked only after I did rebooted Ubuntu 20.04. **Any Suggestion to avoid rebooting?**

Answer (score 0):

It should work in that way. Try letting `/etc/pulse/default.pa` unchanged. Try copying `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to `~/.config/pulse/default.pa`, then add `load-module module-simple-protocol-tcp source=0 record=true port=22345`. Also use pavucontrol to see where your audio comes and goes, it may output to your laptop speakers and also listening in that port, as it is recording your main audio card output.